# How to combine components in HTML header

Tags: html, css, styles

My header has two components; menu button and SVG logo. Here is the [simulation](https://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/EKBRZY) on codepen.

[CSS subset to seed the stackoverflow question]

```
.header-T-1 .header__burger span,
.header-T-1 .header__burger:after,
.header-T-1 .header__burger:before {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px
}
```

How to change the CSS so that, on the same line, the menu button (hamburger menu) is on the left and the SVG logo is on the right?

Comment: A `float: left;` on the `.header__burger` and a `position: absolute; right: 0px;` on `.main-header` will get the menu button on the left and the logo on the right, though I don't know if it's quite what you're looking for.

Comment: Progress - TY. I updated codepen. The change to `.main-header` works as you expected. However, I can't get the `float: left;` change to work as you intended.  I tried it in several locations, but none work. Your suggestion currently is in every directive for `.header__burger`. Any other suggestions for pushing that illusive button left?

Comment: Oops, I forgot that apparently I had also apparently removed the `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -38px;` styles from .header__burger. Also, I think you can just put the float on the main element instead of all of its :before and :after pseudo-elements too.

Comment: TY again for assistance. I've put some analysis and the links to 3 versions here: `http://ontomatica.com/amp_test/_results_.txt`. This may make it easier for you to look at different versions in different browsers.

Comment: The logo reappears in Chrome if you explicitly add width and height. Not sure if that's a possibility for your case. I'm not sure I totally understand what you mean by losing menu selectors (though I admittedly didn't open the menu till your last comment), but you can get the menu to drop down nearer the icon by removing its `left` and `margin-left` values too. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKgGme

Comment: Perfect. Please drop your codepen into an answer and I'll accept it. FYI, it took me quite a while to get the URL selectors to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required changes to get the hamburger menu at top left are to float it and remove its positioning/margin (and that of its dropdown):

```
  .header-T-1 .header__burger {
-     left: 50%;
-     margin-left: -38px
+     float: left;
  }

  .header-T-1 .header-drop {
      width: 409px;
-     left: 50%;
-     margin-left: -204.5px;
      padding-top: 109px
  }
```

And to get the logo at the upper right required the addition of absolute positioning and explicit dimension setting:

```
  .main-header {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    background: #333;
    padding: .5em;
+   position: absolute;
+   right: 0px;
+   height: 25px; /* assuming these are the desired dimensions */
+   width: 250px;
  }
```

Codepen where it should work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKgGme